# Custom Webpart doesn't show up in Sharepoint 2010 after deploying from VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, web-part

Full disclosure: Sharepoint development noob. I currently have 3 custom web parts built in an SP solution in VS2010. I build and deploy my project out to our local Sharepoint dev box. However, after deploying, only the first 2 custom web parts show up under the Custom category in the "insert web part" ribbon section. I checked the elements.xml file for all 3 webparts, they're all set up to be listed under the custom group. Any ideas on how I can debug this? Any constructive advice is greatly appreciated.

Home elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="Home" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="Home\Home.webpart" Url="Home.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

IdeaEditor elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="IdeaEditor" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="IdeaEditor\IdeaEditor.webpart" Url="IdeaEditor.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

IdeaGrid elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="IdeaGrid" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="IdeaGrid\IdeaGrid.webpart" Url="IdeaGrid.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I'm not sure why, but changing the feature name in my solution seemed to fix the problem. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that there are no naming conflicts of your .webpart files. Please update your question with contents of the elements.xml file(s). Have you used several SPI's (SharePoint project items) for the Web Parts or one single?

Comment: Elements.xml file contents added. I'm only use one Sharepoint project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the package editor to ensure that all 3 web parts are being packaged up when you deploy the solution?